Gets different parent paths due to / is this correct behaviour
If you have a path let us say /tmp/test/t then I would expect the parent path to /tmp/test.
Then if we have another path /tmp/test/t/ then I would still expect the parent path to be /tmp/test.
However, the following code shows that this is wrong:
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main(void) {

    auto parent_one = std::filesystem::path("/tmp/test/t/").parent_path();
    auto parent_two = std::filesystem::path("/tmp/test/t").parent_path();

    std::cout << parent_one << "\n";
    std::cout << parent_two << "\n";

    assert(parent_one == parent_two); 
}

Here parent_one is /tmp/test/t and parent_two is /tmp/test, where the later is what I would expect for both calls.
Is this correct behavior for std::filesystem::path?
The code is compiled with g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main with g++ version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.



Basically what the parent_path function does is remove the last path-component up to (and including) the last path-separator. With /tmp/test/t/ that would be just the / at the end.

So yes, that is intended behavior... hmm

Yeah, if you have user-supplied paths you might want to consider cleaning them up before working with them.
